# iOS. stackNavigator. отследить нажатие кнопки назад

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

Разрабатывается приложение на react native под ios и возникла следующая проблема:
Нужно в личной кабинете сделать редактирование полей. Предполагается, что пользователь кликает на одно из полей, его перенаправляет на страницу с редактированием и при переходе на страницу назад, изменения должны быть приняты и поле должно измениться. Собственно, примерно так и работает нативный интерфейс ios. Но как можно отследить нажатие кнопки "назад", если навигация реализована с помощью StackNavigation?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел метод решения проблемы:

```
this.props.navigation.addListener('willBlur', payload => console.log('Страница закрывается'));
```

В моем случае это решение подходит, потому единственная возможность уйти со страницы - нажать кнопку назад